# Post method through Javascript not working but works in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, post, postman

I am trying to send a message to android devices through POST request to Firebase Cloud Messaging . But the server responds with success response 200 when I do the Post Request from POSTMAN .

But when I do the same thing in JAVASCRIPT through AJAX request , I'm Getting error 400 .

How to fix this ?

#### This is the data I send through POSTMAN :-

url :-  "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

Content-Type : "application/json"

Authorization: "key=mykey"

```
{
    "to" : "/topics/global",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
}
```

#### JAVASCRIPT AJAX request :-

If I send the same data from javascript through a AJAX request , I get the response 400.

```
mydata = {
    "to" : "/topics/global",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
}


headers= {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "key=AIzaSy....KC1Q",
}


$.post({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    data: mydata,
    success: function (e) {
        console.log(e+ "SUCESS") ;
    },
    headers: headers
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your key is escaped correctly when inserted like this in js?

Comment: Just looking quickly through this, your ajax request code looks really weird - your options object is outside the brackets, and you have headers = instead of headers:... Are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: You have flat out syntax errors in your JavaScript. That should give you JS errors not a 400. Try showing a real [mcve].

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the syntax error ,  i have corrected them now . Please recheck . I am using the POST method of jquery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `ajax` method to this instead:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
   data: mydata,
   success:function(e){console.log(e)},
   headers: {
       "Content-Type":"application/json", 
       "Authorization":"key=mykey"
   }
})
```